# How can I run Quartz.NET Jobs in a separate AppDomain?

Tags: quartz.net

Is it possible to run Quartz.NET jobs in a separate AppDomain? If so, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What is your usage scenario? If you run your scheduler as a separate windows service from your main application, is it not enough?

Comment: Runtime code isolation is the primary reason. I have a number of unrelated jobs that I want to run (among other things); yet have a common management area. The Quartz jobs are just one part of a larger enterprise integration system.

Comment: @yorah — Often the developer needs to publish an update to the job's assembly, which can't take place if the Quartz service is running. This would mean having to stop the service, publish the update, and then restart the service. This might be acceptable in some situations, but in many situations not. A separate `AppDomain` solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I've not tried this, it's just an idea. And none of this code has been compiled, even.

Create a custom job factory that creates a wrapper for your real jobs. Have this wrapper implement the `Execute` method by creating a new app domain and running the original job in that app domain.

In more detail: Create a new type of job, say `IsolatedJob : IJob`. Have this job take as a constructor parameter the type of a job that it should encapsulate:

```cs
internal class IsolatedJob: IJob
{
    private readonly Type _jobType;

    public IsolatedJob(Type jobType)
    {
        _jobType = jobType ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jobType));
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Create the job in the new app domain
        System.AppDomain domain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("Isolation");
        var job = (IJob)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("yourAssembly", _jobType.Name);
        job.Execute(context);
    }
}
```

You may need to create an implementation of `IJobExecutionContext` that inherits from `MarshalByRefObject` and proxies calls onto the original `context` object. Given the number of other objects that `IJobExecutionContext` provides access to, I'd be tempted to implement many members with a `NotImplementedException` as most won't be needed during job execution.

Next you need the custom job factory. This bit is easier:

```cs
internal class IsolatedJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return NewJob(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }

    private IJob NewJob(Type jobType)
    {
        return new IsolatedJob(jobType);
    }
}
```

Finally, you will need to instruct Quartz to use this job factory rather than the out of the box one. Use the `IScheduler.JobFactory` property setter and provide a new instance of `IsolatedJobFactory`.

Comment: Do you really need the isolated job class, couldn't the appdomain stuff be moved into the factory instead? or would that cause a leak.

Comment: Just re-reading my answer, I think if you could get away without marshalling the original IJobExecutionContext (which seems doubtful) then you wouldn't need IsolatedJobFactory. Otherwise you're going to need to have a hook (i.e. the Execute method in the IsolatedJobFactory) to allow you to transform the IJobExecutionContext argument into something that can be marshalled to the other AppDomain.

Comment: In your `IsolatedJob` class, did you mean to name the constructor `IsolatedJob` instead of `AutofacJob`?

Comment: Good spot on my 10-year-old code! Fixed.